# OnReceive is not called even after BroadcastReceiver is registered

Tags: android, broadcast, android-broadcast

I want to send a `Toast` after the app launches. I'm using Android 9 so I register `MyBroadcastReceiver` not only on the manifest, but, in `OnCreate` too. After that, I use method `sendBroadcast()`. What I expected, OnReceive in MyBroadcast will get called but it's not.

> This method is called when the BroadcastReceiver is receiving an Intent broadcast.

*-Android Developers Documentation*

**AndroidManifest.xml**:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver">
</receiver>
```

**MainActivity OnCreate()**:

```
registerReceiver(new MyBroadcastReceiver(), new IntentFilter());

Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtra("action", 1);
sendBroadcast(i);
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver OnReceive()**:

```
Toast.makeText(context, "toast", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Please attach whole code you did

Comment: @Harshilkakadiya that's my whole code minus what Android Studio build at startup

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager

Answer (score 0):

```
//Declare in Manifest as below
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >  
  <intent-filter android:priority="1000">  
    <action android:name="YOUR_ACTION"/> 
  </intent-filter>  
</receiver>   


// Register in onResume
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("MyBroadcastReceiver");
registerReceiver( MyBroadcastReceiver, intentFilter);

// call it as below
Intent intent = new Intent("YOUR_ACTION"); 
    intent.setPriority(1000);
    Bundle extras = new Bundle(); 
    extras.putString("action", 1); 
    sendBroadcast(intent); 

// Dont forget to unregister it in onPause(). 
// unRegister it in onStop() if registered in onStart().
```

Comment: If you register in onresume you should unregister in onpause

Comment: Thanks for taking time to help me. I did exactly what you wrote and still it doesn't work.

Comment: @ArwyShelke: either you register in onstart() and then unregister in onstop() or you register in onresume() and unregister in paired onpause(). if your code crash, then fix your code but do not spread false info.